# recentsd process has very high memory usage (almost 2GB) - how to fix?

Tags: macos, mail.app, memory, performance

Right now, activity monitor shows that a process called "recentsd" is using 1.82GB of memory (1.08GB compressed, 752MB private) on my MacBook Pro running macOS 10.13.1.

Some googling has lead to the conclusion that the process is somewhat related to the Mail.app and GMail (which I am also using):

- [Memory leak in recentsd and Mail eating up all my RAM](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6639385?tstart=0) (from 2014)
- [Issues with 'recentsd' using all of my RAM](https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/5gjapw/issues_with_recentsd_using_all_of_my_ram/) (11 months ago)
- [macOS runaway process "recentsd"](https://confluence.netfriends.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=65799363) (also mentions 100% CPU load which I don't experience)

The links also give some ideas for a solution (deleting the "com.apple.corerecents.recentsd" folder and reconnecting the gmail account).

However, despite doing that, memory usage of recentsd is still very high (after some time - so it seems to be a continuous growth).

Any idea what else I could try?

Comment: Do you have any memory pressure? Allocating virtual memory and even physical memory means little if the system isn't under pressure.https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/202744/ and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153901/

Comment: @bmike: I noticed the issue first when running a VM which ran very slow and then I noticed that memory pressure was yellow and recentsd (and two other „helper processes“ - one of them was contacts-donation-agent) took more than 8GB together. Killing them, rebooting a couple of times and re-adding the GMail account frees the memory and has solved the issue for now for the others. Just recentsd seems to behave „strange“ still (takes less than 5MB after boot, but then grows).