# Continually getting "you do not have enough application memory" despite plenty free

Tags: macos, high-sierra, memory

A few times recently my MacMini running 10.14.6 gets into a loop of giving this error every few minutes to seconds. This is despite having 1.5-3GB application memory free, according to the Memory Clean 3 app. Even using it to clean the memory doesn't help. Eventually it just grinds to a halt and rebooting is the only answer.

Anyone else seen this, or can suggest a remedy short of rebooting?

Comment: Can you check Activity Monitor and ensure it agrees with Memory Clean 3 regarding free memory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Your system has run out of application memory." How is that possible?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/158639/your-system-has-run-out-of-application-memory-how-is-that-possible) https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/178281/how-to-investigate-high-kernel-task-memory-usage?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/270150/your-system-has-run-out-of-application-memory-but-memory-pressure-is-not-even?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104/

Comment: Boot into safe mode, use the system for a while and boot back to normal mode. It should clear up some files. : https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/377049/313842

Comment: pictures of Activity Monitor may help, too.

Comment: you can get some additional info using right click on the top row in Activity monitor, memory tab: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGzkF.png @jgc